Long decimal point
I've created an algorithm to do long division in C++, but I can't figure out how to place the decimal point properly. I'm beginning to think I need to redo the algorithm.
std::string LoneFunctions::divideDecimalStrings(const std::string& num1, const std::string& num2, int precision) 
{
    int stringDP1 = LoneFunctions::findCh('.',num1);
    int stringDP2 = LoneFunctions::findCh('.',num2);
    
    std::string usedString1 = num1;
    std::string usedString2 = num2;
    int numDecimals,st1Decimals,st2Decimals;
    if(stringDP1 != -1)
    {
        usedString1.erase(stringDP1,1);
        st1Decimals = usedString1.size() - stringDP1;
    
    } else
    {
        st1Decimals = 0;
    }
    
    if(stringDP2 != -1)
    {
        usedString2.erase(stringDP2,1);
        st2Decimals = usedString2.size() - stringDP2;
        ;
    } else
    {
        st2Decimals = 0;
    }
    numDecimals = st1Decimals + st2Decimals;
    
    std::string result;
    std::string current = "";
    std::string temp = "";
    std::string tempB = "";
    std::string quotient = "";
    int numOfDigits = 0;
    int n = usedString1.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        current = usedString2;
        temp += usedString1[i];
        int count = 0;
        while (LoneFunctions::compareStrings(temp, current) || LoneFunctions::isEqual(temp,current)) {
            temp = subtractStrings(temp,current);
            count++;
        }
        quotient += std::to_string(count);
        numOfDigits++;
    }
    if (precision > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < precision; ++i) {
            temp += '0';
            while (temp.size() > 1 && temp[0] == '0') temp.erase(0, 1);
             while (quotient.size() > 1 && quotient[0] == '0') quotient.erase(0, 1);
            int count = 0;
            while (compareStrings(temp, usedString2) || isEqual(temp, usedString2)) {
                temp = subtractStrings(temp, usedString2);
                ++count;
            }
            result += std::to_string(count);
        }
    }
    
    quotient += result;
    
    
    return quotient;

}

This was one of my attempts at making this work, but it won't work because of leading zeroes, and how this algorithm works.
    if (numDecimals > 0) {
        quotient.insert(quotient.size() - precision - numDecimals, 1, '.');
    }


Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifcally you'll need to explain the issue in more details, and describe what is the output you expect vs the output you get.

When you are facing a problem and the solution is "too difficult" you should learn to re-evaluate your design choices. Numbers are not strings. Make a fixed point class to do all your arithmetic, the it will always be clear where your decimal point is.  E.g. have a look at What's the best way to do fixed-point math, and fixed point division : Emulated Fixed Point Division/Multiplication

If you want to demonstrate incorrect code, provide a [mcve]. That along with the actual and expected output makes it clear what you consider a problem. Further, for tasks like yours, step through the code with a debugger. Try to locate a video tutorial showing you how to do that with the IDE you're using. That said, use TDD (Test-Driven Development). It will help a lot for tasks like this.

A number in a string is a zoned binary coded decimal (BCD).  Look up how to do BCD division as a reference.  Also enable your compiler warnings.  Since your code provided does not compile, and cannot reproduce the problem you described, consider providing a [mcve].

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site.  There doesn't appear to be a clear and focused question here.  What exactly is your question?  Why are you showing code that doesn't compile?  How did you test this code?  What input did you give it?  What output did you get?        What output were you expecting to get?

BTW, std::string current = ""; none of the = ""; are necessary.   std::string current; would have initialized the string to the empty string for you without the additional code.

"I can't figure out how to place the decimal point properly" -- The fact that you could describe this functionality so succinctly suggests that it could be its own function, which could tremendously help your question. If this was a separate function, you would not need to show the code that does the division; just provide suitable arguments to the "place decimal point" function as if the division had taken place.
